# Samsung rv515 trackpad issues

Tags: laptop, touchpad, samsung, trackpad

I'm currently on a Samsung RV515 laptop running Windows 7. I'm relatively new to the world of Linux in general, so I started with the Wubi installer to keep things simple. It worked great, however each time I installed it my trackpad would be extremely laggy, in a sense that it was unresponsive, except in small quick and entirely inaccurate bursts.

Since then I've installed it multiple times, run several other forms of Linux based off of Ubuntu such as Linux Mint, and Backtrack, and even booted from a disc (without actually installing) and everything worked great but the trackpad issue persisted, I was able to get a simple USB plug in Dell mouse that worked just fine, but I'd really like to use my trackpad. I've seen another thread or question on this site from a user that I believe is experiencing similar problems, however it was closed without an answer. I've been looking up answers for months now and haven't found any.

Any help would be greatly appreciated (but please be specific, I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux and frankly a complete idiot with minimal knowledge on how the terminal works.) And if it helps the touchpad does work perfectly on Windows 7 normally, or at least I've never had any issues with it outside of Linux.